# Add line to Scatter Plot

Tags: excel, graph, charts, scatter-plot

I did a scatterplot with two data series (blue and orange in the picture). 
The orange line you see that connects the dots I did manually and I am looking for a way to have this automatic through the chart menu in Excel. Any idea who this can be done? 
I am using Excel version 2013
[image]

Comment: Is this your actual data? Or is your data similar? You can probably 'fake' what you want using an area chart, using some tricks from Jon Peltier's website www.peltiertech.com but the exact approach depends on knowing more about your actual data.

Answer (score 1):

The chart type you are trying to create is called a Step Chart. Unfortunately Excel doesn't natively offer this chart type, but there are several ways to fake them in Excel. You can use an XY chart with Error Bars to produce the horizontal lines, or you can use a column chart with extra in-between data points to fill the gaps between your actual data points, and you can probably also use another hack where you tell Excel that the x axis is a date axis.

It's a bit hard to advise which approach would suit you best without knowing whether your actual data matches the example you've posted or whether it differs in some way. If you can elaborate further I'll amend this answer with some examples.

Edit: Since your data is as described, you should be able to use the approaches outlined at https://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/StepChart.html

Or alternately, just add in extra coordinates to direct Excel where to draw the line:

[image]

...and then delete the markers of the data points you want to hide:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes the example I posted matches the real data I am using. I tried using error bars but they do not give me the "step chart effect"

Comment: Cool. I've amended my answer a couple of times to show the result you've described.